# ImageMagik: Blur map a set of images

Tags: image, imagemagick

The example shown on the website is:

```
convert koala.gif blur_map_gradient.gif \
          -compose blur -define compose:args=3 -composite \
          blur_koala_gradient.gif
```

http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/mapping

I'd like to do this for a whole directory of images.

I've looked into using mogrify, but can't figure out how to set the file input/output to run the process on a whole directory.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0):

<strike>You're on the right track with `mogrify`. To use your command as an example, you could do this:</strike>

`mogrify -compose blur -define compose:args=3 -composite *.gif`

This will apply the changes to all the images in the current directory. **This will overwrite the images.** If you do not want to overwrite the original images, you can either make a new directory (let's call it '/home/user/new/') or use the `-format` option to append a suffix to the files.

Here's an example with both options:

`` `mogrify -path /home/user/new/ -compose blur -define compose:args=3 -composite -format "blur.gif" *.gif ``

This will place originalimagename.blur.gif files in /home/user/new/, leaving the originals intact.

I was sure that it was possible to use -compose with mogrify. In actuality, `mogrify` does not recognize the -compose argument.. I think that your best bet is to use a script to loop through each image in the directory and use `convert` on them.

Comment: Ok, awesome if I was doing this `mogrify -compose blur -define compose:args=3 -composite *.gif` where do I input the gradient map?

Comment: See my edit. I'm sorry, I was mistakenly thinking that -compose works with `mogrify`